# querySelectorAll or any other method returning more than one element- not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to fetch a few posts written by the user with php, and write a function with JavaScript that's supposed to cut the post after the 50th character, and add three dots (...). Everything is working fine if i use querySelector(), or getElementById(), but i can't make it work with any multi-element selecting methods like querySelectorAll() or getElementsByClassName(). There are a few posts on the page and i need to select them all.

Here's the HTML with PHP:

```
 <?php while ($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_posts)) : ?>
 <div class="card p-0 m-0 mt-3">
  <div class="card-header  text-white">
    <span>
       <?= $post['title'] ?>
    </span>
 </div>
   <div class="card-body">
     <p class='article'>
        <?= $post['article'] ?>
          </p>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

The rendered HTML

```
<div class="card-header  text-white">
<span>Title </span>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
<p class="text-left article" id="article">
Article</p>
</div>
```

The JS function:

```
function cutLongString() {

    var article = document.querySelector('.article').textContent

    if (article.length > 50) {
      document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = article.slice(0, 49) + '...';
    } else {
      console.log(article)
    }
}
cutLongString()
```

As i said, this way it works, but if i change querySelector to a multi-element selecting method, it says 'article is not defined'.

Comment: `this way it works` No way, it shouldn't. `getElementsByClassName` does *not* return an element, so `getElementsByClassName('article').textContent` won't give you anything. Can you post the *rendered HTML*, not the PHP?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's supposed to be querySelector not getElementsByClassName. I changed it in the post. And yes, i'm posting the rendered HTML

Comment: `querySelectorAll('.article')` sounds like it would *probably* work, though there's not quite enough HTML to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to itereate through all of the element's and set the new `textContent` value one by one:

```js
function cutLongString() {
  const articles = document.querySelectorAll('.article')
  Array.from(articles).forEach(a => {
    if (a.textContent.length > 50) {
      a.textContent = a.textContent.slice(0, 49);
    }
  })
}

cutLongString();
```

```html
<div class="card p-0 m-0 mt-3">
  <div class="card-header  text-white">
    <span>Title </span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <!--Dont assign multiple elements to the same ID. Remove the id="article" below from the <p/>-->
    <p class="text-left article" id="article">Article</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card p-0 m-0 mt-3">
  <div class="card-header  text-white">
    <span>Title </span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="text-left article" id="article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList, so you'd need to iterate over the results:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.article');

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const article = list[i];
    // do something else
}
```

You could also do a forEach(), but since IE11 doesn't support forEach on NodeLists I thought I'd give a way that works in all major browsers.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll for more on querySelectorAll()

Comment: You could iterate over the list by wrapping it with an `Array.from(NodeList)` :)